I would like to know if with this code after deploy on REMIX IDE,it is possible swap my token in bnb,usdt,btc,eth and sol on Uniswap and Pancakeswap
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

interface IPancakeRouter01 {
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}

interface ISwapRouter {
    struct ExactInputSingleParams {
        address tokenIn;
        address tokenOut;
        uint24 fee;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountIn;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
    }

    function exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams calldata params) external returns (uint256 amountOut);
}

contract NeoNobleCrypto is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    IPancakeRouter01 public pancakeRouter;
    ISwapRouter public uniswapRouter;
    address public WBNB;
    address public USDT;
    address public BTC;
    address public ETH;
    address public SOL;

    constructor() ERC20("NeoNoble Crypto", "NEO") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        uint8 _decimals = 10;
        uint256 _supply = 800_000_000 * 10 ** uint256(_decimals);
        address tokenOwner = 0x051913a7290421e3E9c26c3ac62440d424ff2a7B;
        
        _mint(tokenOwner, _supply);

        pancakeRouter = IPancakeRouter01(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E); // PancakeSwap Router V2 Address
        uniswapRouter = ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564); // Uniswap V3 Router Address
        WBNB = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c; // Wrapped BNB Token Address
        USDT = 0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955; // USDT Token Address on BSC
        BTC = 0x321162Cd933E2Be498Cd2267a90534A804051b11; // BTC Token Address on BSC
        ETH = 0x2170Ed0880ac9A755fd29B2688956BD959F933F8; // ETH Token Address on BSC
        SOL = 0x570A5D26f7765Ecb712C0924E4De545B89fD43dF; // SOL Token Address on BSC
    }

    function swapToETH(uint256 amount) external {
        _swap(pancakeRouter, amount, ETH);
    }

    function swapToBNB(uint256 amount) external {
        _swap(pancakeRouter, amount, WBNB);
    }

    function swapToBitcoin(uint256 amount) external {
        _swap(pancakeRouter, amount, BTC);
    }

    function swapToSolana(uint256 amount) external {
        _swap(pancakeRouter, amount, SOL);
    }

    function swapToUSDT(uint256 amount) external {
        _swap(pancakeRouter, amount, USDT);
    }

    function _swap(IPancakeRouter01 router, uint256 amount, address toToken) internal {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        _approve(address(this), address(router), amount);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = toToken;

        router.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount,
            0, // accept any amount of tokens
            path,
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp + 300 // 5 minutes
        );
    }

    function swapToETHOnUniswap(uint256 amount) external {
        _swapOnUniswap(amount, ETH);
    }

    function swapToUSDTOnUniswap(uint256 amount) external {
        _swapOnUniswap(amount, USDT);
    }

    function _swapOnUniswap(uint256 amount, address toToken) internal {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapRouter), amount);

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
            ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: address(this),
                tokenOut: toToken,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp + 300,
                amountIn: amount,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        uniswapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }
}


It looks ok, but it's probably better to test it on a testnet first. The only bug I'm seeing is that you're not setting decimals correctly, so I suggest you change it to 18 (default).
Also remember to add liquidity before trying to swap.
